# Calculate the workload of srs program

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is a real world problem I'm trying to figure out.  This seems like calculus to me, but I didn't take calculus in college so I don't know where to look to solve my problem.  I'd appreciate any help anyone can send my way.

I'm trying to model the workload of an SRS program after a given amount of time.  If you are not familiar with SRS, it's a type of flash card program that increases the card's interval every time you get the a correct answer and sets the interval back to one day if you get the answer wrong.  Ideally I would like to calculate the number of cards you would need to study every day by taking into account the following variables:

- days = number of days since adding the first card
- cards = number of cards added each day
- accuracy = percent correct
- increment = multiple of time added for a correct answer (e.g. a card
  with an interval of 10 days * increment of 250%  = new interval of 25
  days)

I hope this made sense.

Thanks,
Adam